# 3.3.0.M1 : Properties on RelationShipEntity not saved when using CypherRestGraphDatabase?

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I've run into a snag with 3.3.0.M1 - I was much thrilled with the speed increase for the REST remoting, but it seems the relation properties aren't saved properly to the remote DB?

BTW; this worked "as advertised" in 3.2.1.RELEASE :-/

I've got a JUnit test that works beautifully using an Embedded instance, but will fail to retrieve relation properties when using a remoted DB.
Indeed, inspecting the database using the webconsole shows the relations have no saved properties.

Obfuscated code follows:

My `@NodeEntity` has:

```
@RelatedToVia
private Set<MyRelationalEntity> links = Sets.newHashSet();
```

And `MyRelationalEntity` is defined thus:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="RELATION_NAME")
public class MyRelationalEntity {
   @GraphId
   @Id
   private Long graphId;
   @Fetch @StartNode
   private TheEntity left;
   @Fetch @EndNode
   private TheEntity right;

   private String scope;
   ...
}
```

Again, when stored in an embedded instance the `scope` property is stored and retrieved fine, but via the remoted database there is no data :-(

**edit**: However, it seems the `__type__` property is set correctly on the relation

This might be a known issue, but I don't see any filed issues at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j.
But I'm thinking perhaps GitHub isn't used as the ALM?

Thanks!

**Edit 2**: After a bit of debugging, I wonded if [line 192 in EntityStateHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/spring-data-neo4j/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/support/mapping/EntityStateHandler.java#L192) might be the culprit? 
The empty map seems to propagate down to the RestRelationShip class?

Comment: Neo4J server version is neo4j-community-2.1.2 for this test, by the way.

Comment: Same for neo4j-community-2.1.6

Comment: springsource JIRA is used: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH

Comment: what is your code to store it? do you store the relationship entitiy separately? Or just the node-entitiy and the rel-entity automatcally?

Comment: Tried to reproduce but couldn't https://gist.github.com/jexp/48afc53fb630524a05ed

Comment: Hello, and thanks for getting back :-)
I just store the GraphEntities, not the RelationshipEntities.
I'll have a look at your Gist

Comment: Right! I've set up a JUnit test that shows my issue: https://github.com/jhberges/sdn-test/. The test https://github.com/jhberges/sdn-test/blob/master/src/test/java/jhberges/sdn/RelationshipEntityTest.java can be switched between embedded and remoted by commenting out some lines. 

Thanks. // JHB

Answer (score 1):

Ah..

Found this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/spring-data-neo4j/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/support/mapping/SourceStateTransmitter.java#L101

Guess that explains things ;-)

Presumably all will be excellent in 3.3.0.RELEASE - until then I'll prefer slow operation over missing functionality :-)

But, still : great work from the spring-data-neo4j team!

Comment: Not tried it yet, I'm afraid.
The non-proxied approached worked so well I  stuck with it.