# Relationship property not persisted in graph

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

**Context**

- SDN 3.3.0.RELEASE / 3.4.0.M1
- Neo4j 2.1.7 in distant server mode.

**Use case**

I have an existing Person in database which can have multiple PersonTranslatedContent that can be in several languages.
So basicaly, my modelisation is like :

```
(:Person)-[:TRANSLATION {lang:"fr}]->(:PersonTranslatedContent)
```

**Problem**

When I create a PersonTranslatedContent node and a TRANSLATION relation to link with my Person, the 'lang' property is not persisted on the relationship.
The nodes are corecctly created, but when I query the database from the Neo4j browser, my relationship has only one property : `_type__ : PersonToPersonTranslatedContent`

**Analysis**

When logging the HTTP request received by Neo4j, the requets performed are in this order :

```
 1. MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = {id_n}  MATCH (m) WHERE id(m) = {id_m}  CREATE (n)-[r:`TRANSLATION`]->(m) SET r={props}  RETURN id(r) as id, type(r) as type, r as properties, id(startNode(r)) as start, id(endNode(r)) as end
 2. START r=rel({id})  SET r.`_ _type_ _` = {value}
 3. START r=rel({id})  RETURN id(r) as id, type(r) as type, r as properties, id(startNode(r)) as start, id(endNode(r)) as end
 4. **START r=rel({id})  SET r.`lang` = {value}** <-- here the lang property seems to be correctly set !
 5. START r=rel({id})  SET r = {props} <- here, props = {"_ _type_ _" : PersonToPersonTranslatedContent"}
```

All those REST calls are done within a simple call to personToPersonTranslatedContentRepository.save(). I followed the white rabit in debug mode and here is the shortened call stack :

- Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.write() --> entityStateHandler.useOrCreateState() --> RestAPICypherImpl.createRelationship() (**correspond to bullet 1**)
- Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.write() --> typeMapper.writeType() --> RestAPICypherImpl.setPropertyOnEntity() (**correspond to bullet 2**)
- Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.write() --> sourceStateTransmitter.copyPropertiesTo() -->  persistentEntity.doWithProperties() -->  RestAPICypherImpl.setPropertyOnEntity() (**correspond to bullet 4**)
- Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.write() --> sourceStateTransmitter.copyPropertiesTo() -->  ((UpdateableState)target).flush() -->  RestAPICypherImpl.setPropertiesOnEntity() (**correspond to bullet 5**)

So, in my opinion considering what I know and what I saw during debug, the problem seems to be around the "propertyData" attribute of class RestEntity which is used in the ((UpdateableState)target).flush() ! It always hold the value {"_ *type* _" : PersonToPersonTranslatedContent"} but never contains my "lang" property.

**Note** : my problem is the same as the one explain here [3.3.0.M1 : Properties on RelationShipEntity not saved when using CypherRestGraphDatabase?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27861583/4745726). His post has no satisfying answer.

Can you help me (and him I guess) ?

Thx :)

**13/07/15 : Updated**

I finally manage to resolve my problem by using :

`Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("lang", lang);
properties.put("__type__", "UserToUserTranslatedContent");

neo4jOperations.createRelationshipBetween(neo4jOperations.getNode(user.getId()), neo4jOperations.getNode(translatedContent.getId()), RelationNames.TRANSLATION, properties);`

But it is still strange that simple save() operation do not work as expected

Answer (score 0):

For people looking for a fix, I made a report concerning this problem (https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-699) and a quick way to use SDN like before (< 3.3.x) is doing like this:

remove "spring-data-neo4j" and "spring-data-neo4j-rest" from your build.gradle and add these lines:

```
repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm:4.1.7.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.1.7.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.github.nousmotards:spring-data-neo4j:3.3.1.NM1'
}
```

Hope this will help in the mean time of having a real fix ;)